# Creating an nxn alternating matrix using unix commands

Tags: unix, matrix

Anyone know how to create an nxn matrix of alternating 0's and 1's using unix commands?

ex output:

[image: alternating matrix]

I can create a non-alternating matrix by $ yes 1010101 | head -7 but I'm not sure how to alternate the rows

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
if [ $((n%2)) -eq 0 ]; then
    yes 'echo 1; echo 0' | sh | head -$((n*n+n)) | pr -$n -s' ' -t | head -$n
else
    yes 'echo 1; echo 0' | sh | head -$((n*n)) | pr -$n -s' ' -t
fi
```

Basically it prints out alternating 1s and 0s in a single column, then uses `pr` to wrap this column into multiple columns for output.

Answer (score 0):

A year too late, but here you go: 
$ yes "1 0" | fmt -10 |head -7